# GROUP BY with value of column SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sum

I would like to display for a given user percentages by type (M or C)
I tried with this query:

```
SELECT TYPE,user_name,pourcentage_c,pourcentage_m,id_user, 
       COUNT(TYPE) AS crtitique ,COUNT(TYPE) AS majeur
FROM stat_alert  
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_qdf  ON user_qdf.`id` = id_user   
WHERE user_qdf.`id`=id_user AND TYPE='C'
GROUP BY id_user 
UNION ALL
SELECT TYPE,user_name,pourcentage_c,pourcentage_m,id_user,
       COUNT(TYPE) AS crtitique,COUNT(TYPE) AS majeur 
FROM stat_alert  
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_qdf  ON user_qdf.`id` = id_user   
WHERE user_qdf.`id`=id_user AND TYPE='M'
GROUP BY id_user
```

I want to display in the same line the  percentage and the number of critical and important for a single user

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use something similar to this (this is basically a `PIVOT` function).  This performs a `JOIN` on your `user_qdf` table once. You then apply an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement to get the count (using `SUM`) for each of the different `TYPE` values:

```
SELECT TYPE, 
  user_name, 
  pourcentage_c, 
  pourcentage_m,
  id_user,
  sum(case when TYPE ='C' then 1 else 0 end) AS crtitique,
  sum(case when TYPE ='M' then 1 else 0 end) AS majeur
FROM stat_alert  
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_qdf  
  ON user_qdf.`id` = id_user   
WHERE user_qdf.`id`=id_user
  AND type IN ('M', 'C')
GROUP BY id_user
```

Comment: +1 - Would add `AND type IN ('M', 'C')` If more than one type can exist.

Comment: @bluefeet thank you for your answers only concern that remains is percentages i have i.imgur.com/2lP6w.png 
but normally I have 100  pourcentage_m,

Comment: @user1794019 can you create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with a sample schema and working data?

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for, here is a sql fiddle demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf7ac/1

Comment: @bluefeet I thought to change the way we calculate the total number of lines stat_alert tables and percentages to
I tried to add COUNT(TYPE IN ('C','M')), but no positive response

Comment: SELECT  user_name,id_user,COUNT(TYPE IN ('C','M')),
SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE ='C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS critique,
 SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE ='M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS majeur FROM stat_alert LEFT OUTER JOIN user_qdf  ON user_qdf.`id` = id_user 
 WHERE user_qdf.`id`=id_user  GROUP BY id_user

Answer (score 0):

This should work (can't test it right now)

```
SELECT TYPE,user_name,pourcentage_c,pourcentage_m,id_user,
    SUM(CASE user_qdf_c.TYPE WHEN 'C' 1 ELSE 0 END) AS crtitique,
    SUM(CASE user_qdf_m.TYPE WHEN 'M' 1 ELSE 0 END) AS majeur 
FROM stat_alert  
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_qdf user_qdf_c ON user_qdf_c.`id` = id_user AND TYPE='C'
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_qdf user_qdf_m ON user_qdf_m.`id` = id_user AND TYPE='M'
GROUP BY id_user
```

The idea is not to use COUNT, but use SUM instead.

**EDIT** this can be rewritten much better, with using just one LEFT JOIN (which means **a lot** better performance!) see @SashiKant's, and @bluefeet's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
  SELECT 
 TYPE,
user_name,pourcentage_c,pourcentage_m,id_user,COUNT(TYPE) AS crtitique ,COUNT(TYPE) AS majeur
```

FROM stat_alert
        LEFT OUTER JOIN user_qdf      ON user_qdf.id = id_user   and user_qdf.id=id_user TYPE='C' or TYPE='M' GROUP BY id_user

Comment: I would recommend putting `()` around your two `OR` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT user_name, pourcentage_c, pourcentage_m, id_user,  
       COUNT(1) AS crtitique, COUNT(1) AS majeur
FROM stat_alert  
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_qdf ON user_qdf.id = id_user  
GROUP BY id_user, TYPE
```

Comment: thank you for your answers only concern that remains is percentages i have http://i.imgur.com/2lP6w.png

Comment: the column percentage_c when type = 'C'

Comment: column percentage-c shows the percentage when I type = 'C' and porcentagem pourcentage when I display type = 'M' for the sum works perfectly